# How do I apply the same filter to 50+ data frames?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have about 50 unique data frames with the same column names.

Right now I have something like this:

```
df1_cleaned <- df1$price
df1_cleaned <- df1$date 
df2_cleaned <- df2$price
df2_cleaned <- df2$date
...
```

There are 10 columns in the uncleaned data frames, I'm only interested in getting the 3rd and 5th columns of each.

Is there a way to do this without writing out every single data frame?

Cheers

Comment: Use a `list` to store all your `data.frames`, then loop over them. Or probably more sensibly, collect all your `data.frames` into one big `data.frame` and then just select the 3rd and 5th columns once. Something like this sort of logic - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460120/looping-through-list-of-data-frames-in-r or for making one big `data.frame` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162197/combine-rbind-data-frames-and-create-column-with-name-of-original-data-frames

Comment: When you are executing your 2nd statement you are overwriting the 1st one.

Comment: When @thelatemail suggested a `list` of frames, you might use a `for` loop, or more directly you can use `list_of_frames_updated <- lapply(list_of_frames, my_func)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract multiple columns at once from a dataframe by doing `df_cleaned <- df[,c("price","date")]`. But for processing 50 different dataframes (all with the same column names), you can use a `for` loop. Here is a way to do it:

1) define the list of dataframes to be proceed

```r
list_of_df = list.files(pattern = ... , path = ...) # ... stands for argument you have to pass and dependent of your files. check the ?list.files
```

2) loop over the list of dataframes, clean them and assign them to your environment:

```r
for(i in list_of_df)
{
  df = read.table(i,...) # ... stands for arguments to be passed in this function and dependent of your type of file. Check ?read.table 
  df <- df[,c("price","date")]
  assign(paste0(i,"_cleaned"), df,.GlobalEnv)
}
```

Advantages: you will have your 50 dataframe cleaned and ready to be used in your environment. 
Inconvenients: You have 50 dataframes in your environment which can be messy

**Alternative:** As proposed by @thelatemail is to stored these 50 cleaned dataframes into a list. Like that you will have a single object in your environment filled with your dataframes. To do that, the procedure is about the same:

1) define the list of dataframes to be proceed

```r
list_of_df = list.files(pattern = ... , path = ...) # ... stands for argument you have to pass and dependent of your files. check the ?list.files
```

2) Create a list object to stored dataframes

```r
final_list = vector("list", length(list_of_df)
names(final_list) = list_of_df
```

3) loop over your list of dataframes, clean them and add them to the list object:

```r
for(i in 1:length(list_of_df))
{
  df = read.table(list_of_df[i],...) # ... stands for arguments to be passed in this function and dependent of your type of file. Check ?read.table
  df <- df[,c("price","date")]
  final_list[[i]] <- df
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really address the question about how to filter 50+ data.frames.

Answer (score 1):

Turning @thelatemail's comment into answer. Assuming your 50 dataframes are called `df1`, `df2`, `df3` and so on. You could use `mget` to get them in list and select the columns via position

```
temp <- lapply(mget(paste0("df", 1:50)), `[`, c(1,3))
```

Or via names

```
temp <- lapply(mget(paste0("df", 1:50)), `[`, c('price', 'date'))
```

This approach will return you a list of dataframes, if you need individual dataframes separately, do

```
list2env(temp, .GlobalEnv)
```

---

Or combine all the dataframes together and subset only once.

By position

```
temp <- do.call(rbind, mget(paste0("df", 1:50)))[c(1, 3)]
```

Or by name

```
temp <- do.call(rbind, mget(paste0("df", 1:50)))[c('price', 'date')]
```

This approach will give you all the data together in one dataframe.